# KnowRob :: visualisation_canvas(_). Lights not available

Tags: ros, knowrobtutorials, knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
?-  visualisation_canvas(_).
lights() is not available with this renderer.
true.
```

This has got something do to with processing, that I understand.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/139156/knowrob-::-visualisation_canvas(_).-lights-not-available./) by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2014-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is indeed caused by processing, and there's not much we can do about it. It does not affect performance though.

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2014-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1